# SugarCRM - insert new record in relationship table

Tags: sugarcrm

Hi I am testing and trying to insert a record in relationship table but without success. I am trying to enter new row in relationship table using logic hook when I do Save in Contacts module but instead of that I am getting blank  index.php page.
Where is the problem? 
thank you

```
 <?php

    include_once('modules/Contacts/ContactOpportunityRelationship.php');
    class User_hook {

        function insert()
        {
            $instance=new ContactOpportunityRelationship();
            $instance->$contact_id='96163e07-f55a-eb87-251f-513482e4a1da';
            $instance->$opportunity_id='c99178c5-fed5-7092-4a79-4e1da40a1eea';
            $instance->save();

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax should be

```
<?php
$contactId = '96163e07-f55a-eb87-251f-513482e4a1da';
$oppId = 'c99178c5-fed5-7092-4a79-4e1da40a1eea';
$oContact = BeanFactory::getBean('Contacts', $contactId);
$oContact->load_relationship('opportunities');
$oContact->opportunities->add($oppId);
```

Comment: could you please maybe help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254673/sugarcrm-how-to-get-popup-when-click-on-save-button I want to get some pop up when clicking Save (first with some message later I would like to add OK and Cancel options). Thank you in advance

Comment: What if I dont know the value of oppID ? How do I get that ?

Comment: @davidboris what if I need to update a previously added relationship entry?